# python list to columns

Tags: python, pandas

so I have series lists in python variable

```
print(newlist)
0                                    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1         [0.0, 0.0, 0.8784313525490196, 0.5686274509803]
2         [0.0, 0.0, 0.8784313725190196, 0.5686274509803]
3                                    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
4                                    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
5                                    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
6         [0.0, 0.0, 0.8784313724490196, 0.2117647058823]
7                                    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
8                                    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
9         [0.0, 0.0, 0.6274507803921569, 0.8705882352941]
10        [0.0, 0.0, 0.6274509813921569, 0.8705882352941]
```

Now I want each number from the list to be in one column like, I would like the output to look like this,

```
        col1            col2              col3             col4      
0       0.0             0.0               0.0              0.0
1       0.0             0.0               0.8784313525..   0.5686274509803
2       0.0             0.0               0.8784313725..   0.5686274509803
3
4
5
```

similarly to all the rows.
How can I do that using pandas.
please help, Thank you.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/pandas/python-pandas-data-frame-exercise-1.php

Comment: Use `df = pd.DataFrame(newlist.values.tolist(), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])`

Comment: One solution: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html